# remove items using two list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have two lists and i want remove some items from the first list. I don't understand why my code doesn't work.
My input:

```
l0=['Localisation level 2 AM', 'Rang', 'Localisation level 3 AM', 'WP Level 2', 'WP Level 3', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6']
l1=['Localisation level 2 AM', 'Localisation level 3 AM', 'WP Level 2', 'WP Level 3']
```

I try to do this but 'WP Level 2' still in the first list l0:

```
for e in l0:
   if e in l1:
      l0.remove(e)
print(l0)
['Rang', 'WP Level 2', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6']
```

Comment: `l` is not defined, so I'm guessing you mean `l0.remove(e)`. You should not modify a list while iterating over it

Comment: Yes, i mean l0.remove(e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your information, if the order doesn't matter, you can use `set` to accomplish what you want:

```
>>> set(l0).difference(l1)
{'Rang', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your l0 list to another variable. You are removing items while you iterating through a list, so there is your problem. Also, `l.remove` should look like `l0.remove`, because `l` is not defined

```py
import copy
l0=['Localisation level 2 AM', 'Rang', 'Localisation level 3 AM', 'WP Level 2', 'WP Level 3', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6']
l1=['Localisation level 2 AM', 'Localisation level 3 AM', 'WP Level 2', 'WP Level 3']

l00 = copy.copy(l0)
for e in l0:
    if e in l1:
        print(e)
        l00.remove(e)
print(l00)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's a bad idea to modify a list while iterating over it.

The pythonic way to deal with this is to construct a new list and assign it back to `l0`:

```
l0 = [item for item in l0 if not item in l1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l0=['Localisation level 2 AM', 'Rang', 'Localisation level 3 AM', 'WP Level 2', 'WP Level 3', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6']
l1=['Localisation level 2 AM', 'Localisation level 3 AM', 'WP Level 2', 'WP Level 3']

# for e in l0:
#    if e in l1:
#       l0.remove(e)
# print(l0)

l2 = []
for x in l0:
    if x not in l1:
        l2.append(x)
l0 = l2
print(l0)
```

['Rang', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6']

Answer (score 0):

See https://sopython.com/canon/95/removing-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-the-list/

> The reason for this is that the iterator does not know that a list element was removed, and happily advances to the next item.

A better solution would be to use a list comprehension:

```py
l0 = [e for e in l0 if not e in l1]
print(l0)
```

or to iterate reversely:

```py
for e in reversed(l0):
        if e in l1:
            l0.remove(e)
```

or to iterate over a copy of the list:

```py
for e in list(l0):
        if e in l1:
            l0.remove(e)
```